# Angular Guard, ciclo de vida?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hola a todos como están?
Tengo una duda, si me suscribo a un observable desde un guard, tendria que usar ngOnDestroy para romper esa suscription?

Es decir, tiene ciclo de vida el guard como los componentes?

Actualmente, me suscribo al store de redux para obtener data del usuario en el guard y validar si esta autenticado.

**Guard Actual**

```js
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.isLogged()
  }

  canLoad(): | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>
    | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.isLogged()
  }

  isLogged():true | Observable<UrlTree>{
    this.store.select('user').subscribe(userStore => this.token =       userStore.userLogged?.accessToken || '')     
   
    if(!this.token){
      return of(this.route.createUrlTree(['/auth']))
    }
    return true
  }
```

**Mi pregunta es, debería hacer algo como lo siguiente?**

```js
  isLogged():true | Observable<UrlTree>{
    this.storeSubscription = this.store.select('user').subscribe(userStore => this.token = userStore.userLogged?.accessToken || '')        
    if(!this.token){
      return of(this.route.createUrlTree(['/auth']))
    }
    return true
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.storeSubscription.unsubscribe()
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los servicios también llaman al hook `ngOnDestroy` antes de ser destruidos.

El problema es que en el caso de las guardas, como son servicios globales, estos no se destruyen nunca. Por tanto el código que propones no te serviría de nada.

Con la implementación que tienes ahora cada vez que llames al metodo `isLogged` se crea una nueva subscripción indefinida a la store. Si quieres mantener tu implementación, deberás añadirle un operador pipeable como `first` o `take(1)`, para que el observable se complete una vez procesado el primer valor emitido.

De todas formas, como ves, las guardas también pueden devolver el observable directamente, y angular se subscribirá a este automáticamente. Por lo que te recomendaría que refactorizaras tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
isLogged():Observable<true | UrlTree>{
  return this.store.select('user').pipe(
    first(), // tomamos solo el primer valor emitido
    map(userStore => userStore.userLogged?.accessToken || ''), // extremos el token
    map(token => token ? true : this.route.createUrlTree(['/auth'])) // si hay token devolvemos true y sino el UrlTree
  );    
}
```

un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias Akotech. Te quería preguntar, es posible que puedas ver mi otra pregunta en slack, es sobre el unit test de este guard.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/533754/unit-test-angular-a-createurltree